# How to generate random unique sets of two numbers from a given range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate random sets of numbers for x and y from a given a range to be applied in a loop.

I tried the following code but it sometimes returns duplicate values if the 'n' is small or if it loops many times.

```
    x = random.randint(0,n-1)
    y = random.randint(0,n-1)
```

Comment: It's not clear, `x` and `y` shouldn't have intersection? To get set from numbers in some range you can use: `set(random.sample(range(1, 10), k=3))`.

Comment: `if it loops many times.` ...
where is the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the generate x and y in a list. This way you can check if x and y already exist, and if they don't, add new ones.

```
l = []
n = 1
while len(l) < 101:
    if not l:
       x = random.randint(0,n-1)
       y = random.randint(0,n-1)
       l.append((x, y))
    else:
       x = random.randint(0,n-1)
       y = random.randint(0,n-1)
       if (x, y) not in l:
           l.append((x, y))
    n += 1
```

This would give you a unique tuple `(x, y)` every time it loops.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
from random import choice
x = random.randint(0,n-1)
y=  choice([i for i in range(0,n-1) if i!=x])
```

Comment: I do not want the x and y to be different.
I want (x,y) to be different each time.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

after thinking a while, I came up with the following code:

```
n = 5
k = 25
List = random.sample(range(n*n),k)
for i in range(k):
    a = List[i] // n
    b = List[i] % n
    List[i] = (a, b)
```